# AWS cli: set permission to public only to files inside specific "folders"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

So we have 300GB+ of files, in folders like the example above:

1000

```
file.jpg

big/file.jpg

medium/file.jpg
```

2000

```
file.jpg

big/file.jpg

medium/file.jpg
```

How to I set permission to allow anyone to read all objects inside "big" and "medium" in entirely bucket?

Comment: Why the downvote? S3 cli has this bug that if I copy entire bucket to another, it loses all permissions he should keep!

Answer (score 0):

You should use policy as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2).

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/1000/big/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I used S3 cli to copy from one bucket to another, but he lost files permissions! Now I need to set permissions but theres no way to know the resources, maybe I'll have to run a php script or something but it will charge millions of puts.